# When do you get Schneider's Codec frequency?

Tags: metal-gear

So, I was re-playing Metal Gear on the PS2 (which is the MSX version, not the NES version), and Big Boss mentioned calling Schneider to get the location of the gas mask.

However, Schneider has not contacted me at this point... given that this game originally came out in 1987, how am I supposed to get his frequency without resorting to looking it up on the Internet?

Additionally, the game's script implies that he will call you and give you his frequency, but it hasn't happened in any of the rooms I could access using Card 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're supposed to get a call from him on the third floor of building 1, (supposedly it happens in a random room) but it doesn't always happen.  I've seen people say this is a bug, but it's hard to say.

Sometimes he doesn't call you until you've already tried dialing his codec frequency, which has lead some to believe that you're supposed to get his frequency from the (original) game manual.  There's certainly some precedent for this; in other games certain characters' frequency information was hidden on the CD/DVD case or in the manual.

**Update:**  As it turns out, there's a really obscure way of getting the call from Schneider.  While in the room where the west elevator is on the third floor, open the codec and tune past 120.79.  This is the trigger for getting the call.  Credit to [Powerlord](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7342486#7342486) who discovered thisthrough a bit of luck and crazy experimentation.

Comment: This bug must happen a lot.  I just noticed the cached [MGS3: Subsistence FAQ page](http://web.archive.org/web/20060623011430/http://www.konami.com/gs/mgs3_faq.php#56) I have bookmarked for the MG2 Tap Codes list Schneider's MG frequencies.

Comment: Also, I really hate how that link works just fine if I bookmark it, but if I don't, archive.org goes to a landing page instead, breaking the direct link to the question at hand.

Comment: I'm going to point out that not only was I the person to figure it out, but I'm also the person who originally asked the question.

Comment: I’m playing [the Steam version of Metal Gear](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2131680/METAL_GEAR__METAL_GEAR_2_Solid_Snake/), and I found that I had to scroll past the frequency slowly. If I held down left or right, then it wouldn’t work, but if I taped left or right repeatedly, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when Big Boss mentions Schneider, you have to dial him. Then he answers and he tells you where to find the gas mask, or the missile, even from the second floor. His freq. is 120.79.

Comment: What does this add to the already existing answer that is over 1.5 years old?